# How to access US Census TIGER shapefiles in geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, tiger-census

Context: I have a range of ACS data I work with, and I was looking to plot it at the block group level.  However, I am struggling to find the relevant `geometry` objects to actually make such plots.  TIGER files from census (which I think I used back in the early 2010s with geopandas) can't be loaded to `gpd`, and nowhere in the [current TIGER documentation](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgrshp2022/TGRSHP2022_TechDoc.pdf) do they mention a data table with a geometry column.

This stands in contrast to numerous example codes online (eg. [here](https://pygis.io/docs/d_access_census.html) and [here](https://n8henrie.com/uploads/2017/11/plotting-us-census-data-with-python-and-geopandas.html)) that just load TIGER uris into geopandas and implicitly have geometry in the loaded object.

Example code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
# input vars
state_id = 78
year = 2020
file_type='bg'

# load TIGER from URI
uri = f"https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER{year}/{file_type.upper()}/tl_{year}_{state_id}_{file_type.lower()}.zip"
example_blockgroups = gpd.read_file(uri)
```

gives `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'geometry'`

As do other very basic loads of TIGER files like

```
gpd.read_file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020/STATE/tl_2020_us_state.zip")
gpd.read_file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017/STATE/tl_2017_us_state.zip")
gpd.read_file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/TABBLOCK/tl_2019_01_tabblock10.zip")
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this - trying this on GeoPandas 0.12.2 works fine.

Comment: Thanks!  Above is gpd==0.13.0.  If I revert to gpd==0.12.2 I get a different error: `NotImplementedError: A polygon does not itself provide the array interface. Its rings do.`.  What can you load in successfully?  FWIW my gpd is using the fiona engine by default.  Not sure if an engine change would help.

Comment: Working fine for me too, on `geopandas==0.13.2`.